# How to get value of integer element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JQuery and dynamically appending a value to an h1 element using a span element

```
<h1>Height: <span class="height"></span></h1>
```

Now I want to take the value of the span element and use it somewhere else. I tried doing this in JQuery but it's no good.

```
var height = $(".height").val();
```

What is the right way instead?

Comment: you are wanting the text not the value. try .text() instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `span` element doesn't *have* a "value", form elements do.  (`input`, `select`, etc.)  If you're looking to get the *text* of the `span` element, you can do that like so:

```
var height = $(".height").text();
```

Note: If there are multiple matching elements, this will concatenate the text of all of them.  [Observe](https://jsfiddle.net/fcgenoa8/).

Comment: Actually when you call `.text()` it will concat every piece of text from the child nodes.

Comment: @Richard: If there are child nodes, sure.  I guess I inferred from the question that there is a single value in that element.  (Though the question doesn't show *anything* in that element, so anything is possible I suppose.)  If the OP needs to parse more HTML, he/she would need a more specific selector or perform some DOM traversal.

Comment: Don't forget to parse the input value to an actual number, otherwise it's a string not an integer.

Comment: I was referring to this part: >If there are multiple matching elements, this will return the text of only one of them.

Comment: @Richard: Ah, I thought by "child nodes" you meant elements within the `span`.  Interesting, it would appear that you are correct: https://jsfiddle.net/fcgenoa8/  I'm surprised by that, it's different than other similar behavior by things like `.val()`.  I'll update the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this:

```
var height = $(".height").text();
```

note:

val ( ) -> for input element(like: textarea, input etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.

```
Var height=$(".height").text();
```